# Spring Security DelegatingPasswordEncoder doesn't validate passwords that have no prefix

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have recently implemented the DelegatingPasswordEncoder that delegates to PassworEncoders instances upon the prefix of the stored password. The problem is that for the previous stored password that has no prefix it throws an error 'There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"'.I have been told that to defining a default PasswordEncoder to authenticate password that has no prefix the PasswordEncoder prefix has to be specified it in the first parameter of the DelegatingPasswordEncoder () constructor as I specified in the below code example because the stored password are encoded as plain text.

```
@Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
      
        Map<String,PasswordEncoder> encoders= new HashMap<>();
        encoders.put("", NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
        encoders.put("noop", NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
        encoders.put("bcrypt",new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        encoders.put("scrypt",new SCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return new DelegatingPasswordEncoder("noop",encoders);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Passwords with no id, you can set a Default Password Encoder using DelegatingPasswordEncoder method
`setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(PasswordEncoder defaultPasswordEncoderForMatches)`

If this is not set, spring uses `UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder` by default, which throws `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: Can you share the whole PasswordEncoder in this case please?

Comment: @Cugomastik
The PasswordEncoder can be any class that implements the [PasswordEncoder interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html).  
For example, if you want BCrypt to be the default, do something like this
`setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will work also:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
  
    Map<String,PasswordEncoder> encoders= new HashMap<>();
    encoders.put(null, NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
    encoders.put("noop", NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
    encoders.put("bcrypt",new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    encoders.put("scrypt",new SCryptPasswordEncoder());
    return new DelegatingPasswordEncoder("noop",encoders);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've called DelegatingPasswordEncoder constructor with the following signature:

```
public DelegatingPasswordEncoder(String idForEncode, Map<String,PasswordEncoder> idToPasswordEncoder)
```

`idForEncode` param is used to determine which PasswordEncoder to employ when using the `encode()` method. E.g. when a user creates an account or changes their password, your app will hash the password using the PasswordEncoder specified by idForEncode. In your case, NoOpPasswordEncoder.

However, for password matching, such as during a user login, the `matches()` method of the PasswordEncoder is used. DelegatingPasswordEncoder doesn't rely on the idForEncode param for password matching. As mentioned in the verified answer you should use `setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(PasswordEncoder defaultPasswordEncoderForMatches)` method to define the PasswordEncoder to delegate to in case your passwords do not include an id prefix.

Think of a scenario when you decide to change the encoding algorithm in your app for newly registered users to BCrypt, but for old users whose passwords were hashed via NoOpPasswordEncoder & already stored, you want to keep using NoOpPasswordEncoder for match verification:

```
@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
    encoders.put("noop", NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
    encoders.put("bcrypt", new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    encoders.put("scrypt", new SCryptPasswordEncoder());

    var passwordEncoder = new DelegatingPasswordEncoder("bcrypt", encoders);
    passwordEncoder.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());

    return passwordEncoder;
}
```